# How do I search using both and and or?

Tags: support, search

I want to search for questions that are tagged (F# and parsing) or (F# and parser combinators).

> ([f#] [parser-combinators]) or ([f#] [parsing])

When I run the query it is converted to

> [parser-combinators] or [f#] [f#] [parsing]

and returning results like

[Why are RegexParsers definied with “def” instead of “lazy val”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19451016/1243762)

which have no F# tag, but do have the parser-combinators tag.

How do I/can I make a query using both and and or?

Comment: @acheong87 Thanks. I knew this would be a duplicate but didn't find it as nested expressions.

Comment: It's a duplicate, but I wasn't able to find the it's-a-duplicate-of questions without coming to here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always use Google's search capabilities, which does have a sort of AND, OR, and NOT capability (see [link](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/136861?hl=en)) and to make sure that the results returned are only on SO, set the site via `site:http://stackoverflow.com`. This is not as powerful as I'd like because you can't search for tags specifically (that I know), but it's not bad.

Answer (score 1):

Using the default search functionality that will be hard but I believe this [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/149738/find-f-with-two-other-tags) does what you want.

```sql
select distinct 
       p.id as [Post Link]
     , pt.name as s
from posts p
-- question
inner join posts q on q.id = coalesce(p.parentid, p.id)
-- posttype name
inner join posttypes pt on pt.id = p.posttypeid
-- join for AND tag
inner join posttags pta on pta.postid = q.id
inner join tags ta on ta.id = pta.tagid
-- join for OR tags
inner join posttags pto on pto.postid = q.id
inner join tags tor on tor.id = pto.tagid
where ta.tagname = 'f#' -- and
and   tor.tagname in ('parser-combinators','parsing') -- or
and p.posttypeid = 1 --Q
```

Keep in mind that datadumps are only made once a week so you will not see today's questions.